# Cannot import ‘IonicStorageModule’ from @ionic/storage

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I get an error when trying to import 'IonicStorageModule' from @ionic/storage.

Please help.

Comment: With which framework are you using ionic ? (angular, vue or react) cause it will change the way of importing it. see [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage). And can you post your error and the ionic version you're using

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution.

Looks like currently npm doesn't install the latest ionic-version 2 storage module. The following npm install command only installs version 1.9

```
npm install @ionic/storage
```

Force-installing the latest storage module fixed the problem :-

```
npm install @ionic/storage@2.0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I passed by the same problem but I found a different solution. Instead using

```
npm install @ionic/storage
```

I used

```
yarn add @ionic/storage
```

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
```

Im using Ionic version 6.13.0

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with Visual Studio 2017 and the Ionic2 template.
I solved it changing inside the package.json' the release reference of the package @ionic/storage to 2.1.3.

```
"@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
```